# create dynamically label at wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, label

I have a C# code and must it write at xaml.

My code:

```
foreach (item i in List.Items)
{
   Label lb =new Label; 
   lb.VerticalAlignment=Center;
   lb.Content= List.Items.Name;
   lb.Width="120";

   mGrid.Children.Add(lb);
}
```

mGrid is a Grid in my xaml code. List is a List. the list became the content from a file.
if in this file are 2 entry's, i had to create to labels.
if there are 4, i must create 4.
if there are 7, create 7.
and so on.

It works fine with C#, but I have to write it in xaml code. How can I do this?

greetings

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the MVVM Pattern.

That way you have ViewModel class, that holds your list of Items
in an ObservableCollection.

Your list just Binds the ItemsSource to the Collection in the
ViewModel, you do no longer require to create the items in the code behind
or elsewhere.

The width and VerticalAlignment go directly to the XAML as they are
view specific. Even the Label will be in the View,  if you need it,
probably as a ItemsTemplate.

MVVM is explained in this excellent video tutorial by Jason Dollinger 
[which is abailable on Lab49](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650)

It already includes a list and you can see there what to do.

The source code developed in this video is also available
[on Lab49](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2689)

Comment: i create a observable collectuion, bind my list on it and bind the oc to the viewmodel and that's all?^^

Comment: almost, you have to connect your view and your viewmodel, then you are done. At first glance, you can do this in the code-behind. something like: this.DataContext = new MyViewModel(); But better watch the video, it is really explained well there.

Comment: at the moment i have only mobile internet, so i can't whatch the video :(

Comment: There is much information about MVVM in textual form. It is quite self explaining if you already know MVC or MVP. If you have a better connection available, the video is an hour really worth spending.

Comment: and if i don't know mvc or mvp? i work not so long with wpf and xaml^^

Comment: then it is no problem, because this is somewhat quite basic that you would learn anyways. you just reached the point where you can use it and it makes sense.

Comment: i has to write a viewmodel class, which contains the datastructur of the list?
also name, height, width ...
and then create a observablecollection
but how come my list to the collection?
and data template need i too....^^

Comment: It is not so complicated ;) You have a viewmodel class that holds the list, fills it, cares for it. In your view, you just have a listview, and bind the items of the list to it. height, width, alignment are properties of the viewmodel, bind them too. consider your list a list of names. the other properties just handle the appearance of the list.

Comment: yes, but how can i return the height, width or alignment?
i must know the position in the list, to specify it and return same values...
or can you give me a example, how i can do it without?

Comment: perhaps you just do not have to specify. Let the list do it.

Comment: i don't understand... "let the list do?" it has a touch of vodoo!^^
or can you give me a example? 

and it's a littl bit complicated, while the list is in a own class defined and has own properties.... but i think, if i had understand the basic prinzip, i can expand it for the written code^^

Comment: What i wanted to tell is, that the list will know how much space it has and needs, as specified in the xaml. let the XAML do this, don't do it on your own. And watch that video!